# Is this await Task.FromResult necessary?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I've just a question that came to my mind since I've started working on an existing project:
Consider the following snippet of code

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DoSomething(Guid token)
{
 var data= await repository.GetDataAsync(token);

 return await Task.FromResult(Ok(data));
}
```

As far I've seen when using await I can just have  `return Ok(data)`

But I've been told that not using that `Task.FromResult` would lead to async problems... where can I find more info on this point? It's used in Web API Full Framework (not.NET Core)

Comment: No, it's very unnecessary. It won't cause any problems, but it is a lot of completely unnecessary cost

Comment: `Task.FromResult` is generally used when you have an impedence mismatch - you're being forced to implement a method that has to return a `Task<T>` (due to inheritance or an interface definition) but for various reasons your code doesn't have any reason to be async and is already capable of producing a `T`.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely no!

You should use `Task.FromResult(Ok(data))` only if you receive data from the repository synchronously, else if you have at least one `await` keyword it's an unnecessary resources waste.

So, you can rewrite your method this way:

```cs
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DoSomething(Guid token)
{
    return Ok(await repository.GetDataAsync(token));
}
```

Comment: `.Result`: [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Your answer would be improved if you just deleted everything from the phrase *"In this case,"* and below.

Comment: Yep, you're right. It's my fault. I'll correct my answer with this [snippet](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7AHwAEAmARgFgAoIgBgAIiyBWAbmuqIGZGTGyA7PQDe1euMY8mSRgA5GMgLIBDAJZ4AFAEoRYifoD0B+gGc8qgA4WYGepSr79AN2VR6AE2UZlAMSgQAWwBlcysbMnoAXkYATnoAJRgLCBNVDGgATwA6AHEbABEvZQBBEwy8MG12B0dxJhiNT28/QJDLawwIgGp6ACJ6ADN/ANNQjrterWra8T1ao1H2m3oSOccXNybfYbawjD5ooiQsloDEkxwAGwwNROTU9KhsvIxC71Lyyq0s86uMb9+12mM3qjSKp12HT4PX6Q0Ciz2K0mwPEAF81hiqOiqJwpGQZKQEkkUmlMvRqKIanU8QSkAAeJi0AB89BebxKZQq2nJVN0vP0RCERxOw0BN16QWUAQslxgHiKyLW2OxQA===).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, maybe I'm not right, but there is [no synchronization context](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html) at ASP.NET Core, so in that case, it won`t be any deadlock. Moreover, at the link in my previous comment, I add a code snippet and their asynchronous code works pretty well.

Comment: Vladislav you are right, Stephen Cleary's [article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) is about preventing deadlocks. But there are also other problems associated with blocking on async code, beyond deadlocks, like `ThreadPool` exhaustion and loss of scalability.

Comment: Thanks to all, but maybe it's used since in the repository there can be a sync access to some resources??

Comment: I don't think so. If your repository returns `Task<TEntity>` you can use the code from snippet 1, and it should be okay